# Помощь в додумывании над регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго вечера товарищи! Друг попросил написать регулярку для разбора следующего текста :

```
andres"1975"pecd123@hotmail.comPhone: Rating:1First Name: andresLast Name: perezEmails sent: 0Emails received: 277Site: foreignwomen.comUser IP: 67.203.195.128Letters sent: 0

njcarney"050865jc"newjerseycarney@gmail.comPhone: 7325677028 Rating:1First Name: jeffLast Name: cameronEmails sent: 0Emails received: 82Site: foreignwomen.comUser IP: 108.25.19.173Letters sent: 0

Rabmugi"868magus"lhwilli@gmail.comPhone: Rating:5First Name: RabLast Name: MugiEmails sent: 0Emails received: 384Site: foreignwomen.comUser IP: 64.134.172.22Letters sent: 0

Cynn2011"123456"sonayra@hotmail.comPhone: 64314960 Rating:7First Name: CynLast Name: SobrenomeEmails sent: 0Emails received: 21Site: br.singlemenonline.comUser IP: 187.82.88.122Letters sent: 0Received chat commission: no

simplepinay27"melodia"melody27us@yahoo.comPhone: 639205488390 Rating:1First Name: melodyLast Name: aguadoEmails sent: 0Emails received: 21Site: philippine-singles.comUser IP: 125.60.248.154Letters sent: 0Received chat commission: no

michael1153"promo2000"mikell_44@hotmail.comPhone: Rating:7First Name: michaelLast Name: schafferEmails sent: 35Emails received: 324Site: asiansingles.comUser IP: 98.31.59.119Letters sent: 0
```

Я хочу ему помочь, однако не обладаю достаточным знанием регулярок, вот что у меня получилось :

```
preg_match_all('#([a-zA-z0-9]+)\"([a-zA-z0-9]+)\"(.*)Phone\:(\s|[0-9]\s)Rating\:([0-9]+)First\sName\:\s([a-zA-z0-9]+)Last\sName\:\s([a-zA-z0-9]+)Emails\ssent\:\s([0-9]+)Emails\sreceived\:\s([0-9]+)Site\:\s(.*)User\sIP\:\s(.*)Letters\ssent\:\s([0-9]+)Received\schat\scomission\:\sno\s#', текст выше, $found);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, особенно запутался с Phone: где телефон может быть, а может его здесь и не быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проходит все ваши тесты:

```
#([0-9A-Za-z]+)\"([0-9A-Za-z]+)\".*Phone: ?([0-9]+)? ?Rating:([0-9A-Za-z]+) Name: ([0-9A-Za-z]+) Name: ([0-9A-Za-z]+) sent: ([0-9A-Za-z]+) received: ([0-9A-Za-z]+)?Site: (.*) IP: ([0-9\.]+)Letters sent: ([0-9]+)(Received chat commission: ([A-Za-z]+))?#s
```